# Sortable columns by meta value holding a date - can't get it to work

Tags: columns

I'm trying to sort the posts (in the edit screen (wp-admin/edit.php)) by meta value corresponding to an event date but I can't get it to work properly...

For example, `ASC` returns:

2012/10/12 
2012/12/11 
2012/09/7

and `DESC` returns:

2012/09/7 
2012/12/11 
2012/10/12

I'm using the following functions to create the sortable custom columns:

```
function event_date_column_display( $name ) {
    global $post;
    switch ($name) {
        case 'event-date':
            $pid = $post->ID;
            $event_date = get_post_meta($pid, '_event_date', TRUE);

            if ($event_date) {
                echo $event_date;
            }
    }
}

function event_date_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['event-date'] = 'event-date';  
    return $columns;
}
```

Any hint on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not an option to insert the sorting directly to the WP_Query class? It has all the parameters for handling this kind of situation http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

If you want to do that in the code, you can first validate all the dates, then convert them to the standard ISO(yyyy-mm-dd) format & then use the standard php functions to sort them like `sort`, `ksort`, (`usort` combined with `strcmp`) or any other depending on your data